# Dynamically instantiating a prefab c# based on list

Tags: c#

I am trying to populate a panel with a prefab when the player has an upgrade available however I am getting an error with my current code and in the console i am getting the following error

`InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

The following code block is causing this error

```c#
GameObject currentTable = upgradeTable[upgradeTableLevel - 1];
        if(GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades != null){
            foreach(Upgrade upg in GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades){
                GameObject go = Instantiate(upgradePrefab,currentTable.transform);
                go.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = upg.ToString() + "(level: " + GameManager.Instance.upgrades[upg] + ")";
                go.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Buy for " + GameManager.Instance.GetNextCost(GameManager.Instance.upgrades[upg]).ToString() + " units";
                GameManager.Instance.DisplayedUpgrades.Add(upg);
                GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades.Remove(upg);
            }
        }
```

This code is also spawning multiple of the prefab

The goal behavior was for the `List` "AvailableUpgrades" to be populated with upgrades when they are available which is done with this piece of code

```c#
public void UpdateAvailableUpgrades(){
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Upgrade,int> cur in upgrades) {
            if (units >= GetNextCost(cur.Value)) {
                if (!AvailableUpgrades.Contains (cur.Key) && !DisplayedUpgrades.Contains(cur.Key)) {
                    AvailableUpgrades.Add (cur.Key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Once an upgrade is available this code block is called

```c#
#region UpgradeTable
        int upgradeTableLevel = GameManager.Instance.FetchUpgradeLevel(Upgrade.UpgradeTable);
        upgradeTable[upgradeTableLevel - 1].SetActive(true);
        foreach(GameObject go in upgradeTable){
            if(go != upgradeTable[upgradeTableLevel - 1]){
                go.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

        //TODO
        //Add a way to find the currently active table and add new upgrades prefab there
        //TEMP SOLUTION
        GameObject currentTable = upgradeTable[upgradeTableLevel - 1];
        if(GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades != null){
            foreach(Upgrade upg in GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades){
                GameObject go = Instantiate(upgradePrefab,currentTable.transform);
                go.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = upg.ToString() + "(level: " + GameManager.Instance.upgrades[upg] + ")";
                go.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Buy for " + GameManager.Instance.GetNextCost(GameManager.Instance.upgrades[upg]).ToString() + " units";
                GameManager.Instance.DisplayedUpgrades.Add(upg);
                GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades.Remove(upg);
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Whats happening here is im getting the table level(needed for grabbing the currently active table and other unrelated stuff) once we get down to `//temp solution` I am grabbing the currently active table. Then checking to see if there are any upgrades in the `AvailableUgrades` if so I loop through the list to instantiate a new upgrade prefab for each upgrade in the list at the end of this list the upgrade is removed from `AvailableUpgrades` and added to `DisplayedUpgrades` I added 2 list for handling this to solve the issue of it constantly spawning new prefabs but it is still spawning them

So how do I fix my script to provide the expected behavior?

Comment: You're callingremove on a collection which is being iterated on in a for each loop. The collection has therefore changed when it goes to re-loop the 2nd time causing this Exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Milney, `foreach` loops do not allow you to alter the enumeration being iterated for safety reasons. It is usually a good practice to avoid this sort of operation anyway since it can easily lead to nasty bugs. If you wish to do it anyway (as I have done it myself a few times), you can do it with `for` loops instead of `foreach`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades.Count; i++) {
    // Do you thing
    if (/*some possible condition*/) {
        GameManager.Instance.DisplayedUpgrades.Add(/*some new Object*/);
    }
    if (/*another possible condition*/) {
        GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades.RemoveAt(i);
        i--; // Since i is pointing to current object that was just removed
        // Otherwise you'd skip one object
    }
}
```

I repeat. **This kind of code can easily lead to hard-to-track bugs** and is also **hard to understand for newcomers in your project** so recommend you try to avoid messing with the enumeration during the loop when possible.

**Edit:** Or... since I noticed your code does not check for conditions to remove each object you could simply call `GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades.Clear()` after the loop to remove all objects.

Comment: Yea I slightly feel as if I coded myself into a corner with this one I just dont see another way around it without reprogramming several other parts of the game

Answer (score 2):

The error explains clearly, the collection you are enumerating here;

```
foreach(Upgrade upg in GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades){
 ...
```

Is then modified here, which is still inside the loop (enumeration);

```
         GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades.Remove(upg);
 }
```

You simply need to instead maintain a list of upgrades to remove, and then remove them after the loop is finished.
So make a new list of upgrades, change the .Remove to add it to this new list instead [upgradesToRemove.Add(upg)], and then after the loop is finished you can remove all the upgrades in the new list from the GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades, since it is no longer being enumerated when you are outside the loop. Ez.

Comment: Another option is to change the `foreach` to a `for` loop, and go through the list backwards.

Comment: It is even simpler then that: since the code removes every single upgrade from the available upgrades list, it is possible to iterate over the list (without removing anything from it) first and do GameManager.Instance.AvailableUpgrades.Clear() right after that.

Comment: Since I am calling the loops every frame @rs232 works perfectly if i call it right after the loop